# var is not updating in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm making an app with React and Express, and I'm facing a basic issue.
I've created a let maxPlayers = 0;
Then I call my DB to find the actual max players number :

```
let maxPlayers = 0;

// Here I ask my DB to count my players
db.query("SELECT * FROM cards", (err, rows) => {
       console.log(rows.length) // -> 30
       maxPlayers = rows.length // In my logic, 0 becomes 30
       console.log(maxPlayers)  // -> 30
   });

   console.log(maxPlayers)      // -> 0
```

What I want is myMaxPlayers to be set as 30 outside the db.query function.

I know this is a basic scope issue, but I've tryied everything i know and i struggle.

Comment: use ```async await```I think it should solve this issue

Comment: yep indeed, I didnt know how to use them, but its working as expected now. thanks !